# how to take ActiveRecord associations to the DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, console

I execute the following commands to make the model:

```
script/generate model user firstname:string lastname:string

script/generate song group songname:string songtitle:string
```

a `user has_many :songs` and a `song belongs_to :user`

after this I run `rake db:migrate` however, the associations are not carried to my actual DB.  Because in my actual DB I do not see any `user_id` column in `songs table`...etc.

Do we have to manually change the migration and add the needed columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you need to explicitly add the `user_id` to the migration file or when you are generating the model.  I do now know of a way for it to detect the association and create the user key at least from the generate line:

I believe your options are:

```
script/generate song group songname:string songtitle:string user_id:integer
```

Or in the migration - adding this to your migration file:

```
t.integer :user_id
```

Or also adding this to your migration file.  I don't believe you can do this from the command line.  And you will need to do it after you create the `belongs_to :user` association in your `songs.rb` model.

```
t.references :user
```

As a note, I generally take the second option.

One other aside just on general ruby/rails convention - generally attribute names are lowercase and separated by underscores.  so `song_name` instead of `songname`.  That is entirely a taste thing and up to you as to how you want to implement.

I hope this helps!